# Mocha: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

The app structure is like this:

`index.js
-src
--db
---index.js
---model.js
-test
--test.js`

In my index.js, I have to import database like this

`const db = require('./src/db')`

The app runs well when use `npm run`
However, when I try to run the test with mocha, it gives me error

`Error: Cannot find module './src/db'`

My test.js file is below:

```js
// Dev-Dependecies
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const should = chai.should()

const app = require('./index')

chai.use(chaiHttp)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `const app = require('../index')`?

Comment: As @JohannesMerz's comment above, your relative link was incorrect.